# JavaFX I can't draw anything on canvas created in Scene Builder

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, scenebuilder

I created scene in SceneBuilder which included canvas object. Now I'm trying to draw anything on canvas, but nothing appear. Maybe someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advice.

Here is declaration of canvas object:

```
public class ApplicationControler implements Initializable {

  @FXML
    public Canvas artHorizon;
```

And the method which should draw something on it:

```
public void drawOval(){
    artHorizon = new Canvas(400, 400);
    GraphicsContext gc = artHorizon.getGraphicsContext2D();

    gc.setFill(Color.DARKRED);
    gc.fillOval(110, 30, 50, 50);
}
```

And the Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/MainPane.fxml"));
    Parent parent = fxmlLoader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(parent);


    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Login Page");
    stage.show();

    ApplicationControler controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
    controller.drawOval();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: artHorizon = new Canvas(400, 400); This may be your problem. I have never tried to draw on a canvas, but atrHorizon is already created and you are creating a new one.

Comment: I have never tried controller.drawOval(); in main. Why not create a button that when pressed draws a shape or put a system.out.println("hello") inside drawOval to make sure it's runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove:

```
artHorizon = new Canvas(400, 400);
```

See if you can do something like this:

```
artHorizon.setHeight(400);
artHorizon.setWidth(400);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've already used the annotation `@FXML` so your Canvas is already initialized "`fx:id`" (in the FXML file) when you load your controller so try removing the Instantiation you can use directly the annotated canvas :

```
artHorizon = new Canvas(400, 400); // to delete
```